# Python Time Function

Tags: python, function, time

I am trying to create a function with Python that accepts an integer as input, representing a number of hours. It should return a tuple of that number converted to minutes (* 60), and then that number converted to seconds. Below is my current code, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def convert_nums(num):
  x = int(num) * 3600
  y = int(num) * 60
  return x,y

print convert_nums
```

Comment: You need to actually call it with e.g. `(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your argument with your print.

Comment: yes you can. Try it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the method call where you are printing.